# c function pointers explanation

Tags: c, function, parameters, function-pointers

I have found some code that I need to use for my application but there are two lines in it I can't figure out what exactly do they do and how... Please, either explain them to me or direct me to a link so I can read more about it.

```
Dict* dcreate(hash_size size, hash_size (*hashfunc) (const char *));
```

Here I guess it is passing a function as a parameter with it's parameter in the following bracket!?

```
hash_size i = dict->hashfunc(key) % dict->size;
```

and here, my guess is as good as my dog's!

The `hashfunc`:

```
static hash_size def_hashfunc(const char* key){
    hash_size s = 0;
    while(*key){
        s += (unsigned char) *key++;
    }
return s;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What they said. Also, you have "hash" in your tags, but it doesn't matter what the functions do; this mechanism is the same for non-hash-related functions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first line, your guess is correct. That is the header for a function that accepts two arguments, one of which is of the `hash_size` type, and another which is a pointer to a function whose argument is a `const char*` and returns a `hash_size`.

In the second line, `dict` appears to be a pointer to a struct, so `dict->hashfunc(key)` calls the function `hashfunc`, a pointer to which is stored in the `dict` struct. The last part (`... % dict->size`) is just the modulo operation.

Answer (score 3):

```
hash_size (*hashfunc) (const char *)
```

Is a **Function Pointer**.

`hashfunc` is a pointer to a function which receives a `const char *` as an argument and returns a type `hash_size`.

Answer (score 1):

It only passes a function pointer as a parameter. The following is the definition of the function type that should be passed:

```
hash_size (*hashfunc) (const char *)
```

E.g. a function that receives a `const char *` and returns `hash_size`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a function pointer

```
hash_size (*hashfunc) (const char *)
```

So that dcreate() will allocate an Dict and fill its field hashfunc like:

```
Dict * dict = (Dict *) malloc(sizeof(Dict));
dict->hashfunc = hashfunc;
```

Then you may call dict->hasfunc(const char *), it will return hash_size.

```
hash_size i = dict->hashfunc(key) % dict->size;
```

It is indeed:

```
hash_size i =  ( dict->hashfunc(key) ) %  ( dict->size ) ;
```